# How do I get the top most view and use it present a specific view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scene

How do I get the top most view in SwiftUI? I have some shortcuts for my app. I want to use top most view present a specific view when shortcut invoke `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)` , or there are other solution?

Comment: Use EnvironmentObject and pass it to the subviews

Comment: @davidev  That means I need add `sheet(isPresented` to every view?

Comment: @MorningStar did you get the Answer?

Comment: @SouravMishra Didn't so far.

Comment: I found 2 ways. Using environment or using a global variable